# Gzip file not being served with node express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, gzip

I'm trying to serve a gzipped file using node/express for a react app, but I keep getting the large 1.2MB file instead of the gzipped 300kb file. Here's the express route handler I'm using

```
router.get('/javascripts/bundle.js', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('ENVIRONMENT')
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    console.log('request URL: ' + req.url);
  }
  next();
});
```

I'm checking to make sure the environment is production, but none of these logs are showing up in my server logs (heroku logs). And looking at the network tab in chrome it shows 1.2MB

is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please post the response code as well- not just this middleware

Comment: @JLivengood I dont have any specific response code for the bundle.js file, maybe that's my issue? I followed a tutorial and it only said to add the middleware

Comment: Oh no, just making sure, I may have a solution. Testing locally

Comment: @JLivengood ok, this is the tutorial by the way, the middleware part is mentioned at the bottom: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a

Comment: Is `console.log('ENVIRONMENT')` logging?

Comment: @JLivengood nope, nothing is logging, its like the middleware is being skipped completely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156603/discussion-between-j-livengood-and-duxfox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe in another module (like app.js) you are using the express static middleware that is catching the request before it can reach your custom middleware.
Check and comment out (if you can)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```